# Is there any disadvantage in saving output of a function to a val?

Tags: scala

I have a function toFoo that merges two data types: bar and baz. Is there any harm in doing the following?

```
val foo = toFoo(bar, baz)

serve(foo)
```

the val foo is not used in any other code. Is it more efficient to do the following instead? What is the difference?

```
serve(toFoo(bar, baz))
```

Am I using less memory in the 2nd snippet since im not saving anything to val foo?

Comment: Efficiency doesn't come into it here. If it helps readability to have the variable, then do it. In his book _Tidy First?_, Kent Beck refers to such variables as "explaining variables".

Comment: Any halfway decent language implementation made in the last 40 years will inline this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency doesn't matter here at all (assignments are rather cheap, and this one will most probably just be optimized away anyhow), and you would not be using any more (heap) memory, because you are only assigning a reference, and local variables live on the stack, so it is a question of style/taste and readability.

Someone mentioned in the comments that intermediate variables make the code more readable. I think, it is really the opposite of that. Especially, when a function is rather long and has complicated logic, having many one-time-use variables just clutters the view and makes the reader waste cycles on tracking them all.

My rule of thumb is to only assign a value to a variable if you are going to use it more than once. There are exceptional use cases, and special constructs (like for-comprehension) when it makes sense to assign every statement to a variable, but most of the time, I wouldn't do it.

Take a look at `ChainingOps`. There are two functions there - `tap` and `pipe` – that lots of pre-2.13 codebases used to just implement on their own in order to handle cases exactly like your example. They let you do things like this:

```
import scala.util.chaining._
toFoo(bar, baz).pipe(serve)
```

Or, maybe:

```
import scala.util.chaining._
toFooBar(bar, baz)
  .tap(log.info("Foobar: " + _))
  .pipe(serve)
```

I would say this makes the code more readable, then the "traditional way", because it explicitly outlines your intent as a single chain of transformations.

This question should really be closed, because it is totally opinion based though :)

Comment: Dima, sorry, but _No_. Your example doesn't do anything that would not be achievable with `log.info("Foobar: " + foo)` and `serve(foo)`. Almost everyone immediately understands how local variables work. Almost nobody knows what `tap` and `pipe` are, or why they would want to write their code in point-free style. This is just adding multiple ways of doing the same thing, using rather obscure & uncommon helper methods. Unless you are porting some Haskell algorithm that has been written in this style, there is no real reason to use it.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Huh? Did I say that it did anything that would not be achievable otherwise??? Moreover, what you wrote, is also "achievable" with something like `val foobar = "Foobar"; val colon = ":"; val foobarWithColon = foobar + colon; val space = " "; val foobarWithColonAndSpace = foobarWithColon + space; val logMessage = foobarWithColonAndSpace + foo; log(logMessage)` ... It is certainly _achievable_ this way, just silly.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin And re. "almost everyone ... " and "almost nobody ...": sure ... "almost everyone" knows what `var i = 0; while(i < x.length) { println(x(i); i +=1; }`  does, and "almost nobody knows" what's `x.foreach(println)` ...  Which is also  just "adding multiple ways to do the same thing". But, what is it you want to infer from that fact?
There are _always_, _a lot_ of "multiple ways to do the same things", some of them are better than others ...

Comment: _"some of them are better than others"_ - yes, and in the case of variables-vs-pointfree, pointfree always loses. This happens as soon as you have to reuse any intermediate result twice: then you are forced to introduce something like [DUP](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/2-stack-manipulation-operators-arithmetic/), and before you know, you've reimplemented some ungodly chimeric hybrid between a [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) and a [Categorical Abstract Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_abstract_machine).

Comment: ... and this never worked. It's not like nobody tried to make it work [(I would claim that I tried hard enough)](https://github.com/tyukiand/bccc_morphism_construction?tab=readme-ov-file), but it always turns out that it's not something worth doing manually, and that you always want to have a compiler in between that translates plain variables into whatever your underlying point-free abstract machine wants to have. It's a trap. So, I see no reason to suggest it to a new Scala user.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Sure, when you "have to reuse intermediate result" you need to modify the code (otherwise, you would not be able to reuse it). So, _that_ would be the time to add a variable. No idea what you mean by "DUP", but if it is something bad, a simple solution is: just don't do it, use a variable instead. That would be a _different_ scenario though (there is no "DUP" here). Re "this never worked": _sure_ it has! :D . And NO, it is NOT any kind of a "trap", and I see no reason to suggest that it is to a new scala user.